# Is the supremum of an almost surely continuous random function random variable?

Tags: continuity, proof-writing, stochastic-processes, supremum-and-infimum

Let {$X_t, t\in[0,1]$} on {$R, \mathfrak B(R) $} be random, almost surely continuous, function. How to show that $X^+=sup_{t \in[0,1]} X_t$ is random variable ?

---

Perhaps here I can say that $X_t$ it will be a random variable $\forall t$ аnd prove the statement like for random variables  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X^{+}=\sup\{X_t: 0\leq t \leq 1,t\in \mathbb Q\}$ outside a null set, so $X^{+}$ is almost everywhere equal to a random variable. So $X^{+}$ is Lebesgue measurable. It need not be measurable w.r.t the Borel sigma  field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand, why can we say, that $X^+$ is random variable? I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: I think you have to look at the source for definitions. A random function is usually defined as a collection of random variables. so it is assumed that each $X_t$ is a random variable. Otherwise there is no hope whatsoever of proving that $X^{+}$ is a random variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it became clearer.